# Tomcat web server restarts automatically

Tags: java, tomcat, webserver, alarm

We have Tomcat web server as a service that has 4 web applications deployed on it. One of them is ALARMCFG, an alarm reporting application.
Sometimes this web server is restarting automatically, we don't have anything logged in the logs of deployed applications.

Want to know the reason of this web server restart. The frequency is random, sometimes daily, sometimes twice a day, sometimes twice a week.
Can someone help in understanding what is the problem and what else has to be checked.

- Java version - jdk1.8.0_333
- Tomcat version - apache-tomcat-8.5.79

**web server restart logs**

```
    {root} #: journalctl -u abc-webserver

    Mar 01 15:34:45 rc5abcco systemd[1]: abc-webserver.service: main process exited, code=killed, status=6/ABRT
    Mar 01 15:34:45 rc5abcco systemd[1]: Unit abc-webserver.service entered failed state.
    Mar 01 15:34:45 rc5abcco systemd[1]: abc-webserver.service failed.
    Mar 01 15:35:00 rc5abcco systemd[1]: abc-webserver.service holdoff time over, scheduling restart.
    Mar 01 15:35:00 rc5abcco systemd[1]: Stopped The abc Webserver Service.
    Mar 01 15:35:00 rc5abcco systemd[1]: Starting The abc Webserver Service...
    Mar 01 15:35:12 rc5abcco abc_smf_start_stop.sh[2532]: webserver is running OK
    Mar 01 15:35:12 rc5abcco systemd[1]: Started The abc Webserver Service.
    Mar 01 22:33:36 rc5abcco systemd[1]: abc-webserver.service: main process exited, code=killed, status=6/ABRT
    Mar 01 22:33:36 rc5abcco systemd[1]: Unit abc-webserver.service entered failed state.
    Mar 01 22:33:36 rc5abcco systemd[1]: abc-webserver.service failed.
    Mar 01 22:33:51 rc5abcco systemd[1]: abc-webserver.service holdoff time over, scheduling restart.
    Mar 01 22:33:51 rc5abcco systemd[1]: Stopped The abc Webserver Service.
    Mar 01 22:33:51 rc5abcco systemd[1]: Starting The abc Webserver Service...
    Mar 01 22:34:02 rc5abcco abc_smf_start_stop.sh[44678]: webserver is running OK
    Mar 01 22:34:02 rc5abcco systemd[1]: Started The abc Webserver Service.
    .
    .
    .
    Jun 01 09:48:58 rc5abcco systemd[1]: Stopped The abc Webserver Service.
    Jun 01 09:49:10 rc5abcco systemd[1]: Started The abcWebserver Service
```

**Catalina.out**

```
    # A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
    #
    #  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007fe638000368, pid=54728, tid=0x00007fe625309700
    #
    # JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_333-b31) (build 1.8.0_333-b31)
    # Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.333-b31 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
    # Problematic frame:
    # C  0x00007fe638000368
    #
    # Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
    #
    # An error report file with more information is saved as:
    # /tmp/hs_err_pid54728.log
    [thread 140626492360448 also had an error]
    [thread 140626582980352 also had an error][thread 140626573510400 also had an error][thread 140626420045568 also had an error][thread 140626442094336 also had an error]
    
    
    
    [thread 140626437883648 also had an error]
    [thread 140626548127488 also had an error][thread 140626414782208 also had an error][thread 140626567083776 also had an error]
    
    
    #
    # If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
    #   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
    # The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
    # See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
    #
    Jun 01, 2023 9:49:00 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
    WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server} Setting property 'command' to 'SHUTDOWN' did not find a matching property.
    Jun 01, 2023 9:49:00 AM org.apache.catalina.mbeans.AbcGlobalResourcesLifecycleListener 
    INFO: AbcUserDatabaseMbean descriptor loaded
    Jun 01, 2023 9:49:00 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: Server version name:   Apache Tomcat
    Jun 01, 2023 9:49:00 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: Server built:          May 16 2022 15:36:23 UTC
    Jun 01, 2023 9:49:00 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: Server version number: 0.0.0.0
    Jun 01, 2023 9:49:00 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: OS Name:               Linux
    Jun 01, 2023 9:49:00 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: OS Version:            3.10.0-1160.80.1.el7.x86_64
    Jun 01, 2023 9:49:00 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: Architecture:          amd64
    Jun 01, 2023 9:49:00 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: Java Home:             /abc/sw/runtime/jdk1.8.0_333/jre
    Jun 01, 2023 9:49:00 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: JVM Version:           1.8.0_333-b31
    Jun 01, 2023 9:49:00 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
    Jun 01, 2023 9:49:00 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: CATALINA_BASE:         /abc/sw/runtime/apache-tomcat-8.5.79
    Jun 01, 2023 9:49:00 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: CATALINA_HOME:         /abc/sw/runtime/apache-tomcat-8.5.79
    Jun 01, 2023 9:49:00 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: Command line argument: -Xmx512M
    Jun 01, 2023 9:49:00 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: Command line argument: -DHEAP_SIZE=512M
    Jun 01, 2023 9:49:00 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: Command line argument: -Dpname=WebServer
    Jun 01, 2023 9:49:00 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: Command line argument: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=
    Jun 01, 2023 9:49:00 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=/abc/sw/runtime/tomcat
    Jun 01, 2023 9:49:00 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=/abc/sw/runtime/tomcat
    Jun 01, 2023 9:49:00 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: Command line argument: -Djava.io.tmpdir=/abc/sw/runtime/tomcat/temp
    Jun 01, 2023 9:49:00 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: Command line argument: -DLOG_DIR=/abc/log/sw_log
    Jun 01, 2023 9:49:00 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: Command line argument: -DCONF_DIR=/abc/sw/conf
    Jun 01, 2023 9:49:00 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: Command line argument: -DRT_DIR=/abc/sw/runtime
    Jun 01, 2023 9:49:00 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: Command line argument: -Djava.rmi.server.codebase=file:///abc/sw/platform/common-R29H01_EC01b1486/dclib/common.jar file:///abc/sw/platform/engine-R32H01_EC05b3632/dclib/engine.jar file:///abc/sw/platform/licensing-R26G01b491/dclib/licensing.jar file:///abc/sw/platform/scheduler-R25H04b525/dclib/scheduler.jar file:///abc/sw/platform/symboliclinkcreator-R19H09_EC02b369/dclib/symboliclinkcreator.jar
    Jun 01, 2023 9:49:00 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
    Jun 01, 2023 9:49:00 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: Command line argument: -Dlog4j2.configurationFile=file:/abc/sw/runtime/apache-tomcat-8.5.79/webapps/adminui/conf/adminui.properties
    Jun 01, 2023 9:49:00 AM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
    Jun 01, 2023 9:49:00 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
    INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["https-jsse-nio-8443"]
    Jun 01, 2023 9:49:00 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
    INFO: Initialization processed in 678 ms
    Jun 01, 2023 9:49:00 AM com.abcdef.catalina.users.AbcUserDatabaseFactory getObjectInstance
    INFO: ABC UserDatabase successfully created.
    Jun 01, 2023 9:49:00 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
    INFO: Starting service [Catalina]
    Jun 01, 2023 9:49:00 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
    INFO: Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat]
    Jun 01, 2023 9:49:00 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
    INFO: Deploying web application directory [/abc/sw/runtime/apache-tomcat-8.5.79/webapps/ROOT]
    Jun 01, 2023 9:49:01 AM org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars
    INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
    Jun 01, 2023 9:49:01 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
    INFO: Deployment of web application directory [/abc/sw/runtime/apache-tomcat-8.5.79/webapps/ROOT] has finished in [616] ms
    Jun 01, 2023 9:49:01 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
    INFO: Deploying web application directory [/abc/sw/runtime/apache-tomcat-8.5.79/webapps/host-manager]
    Jun 01, 2023 9:49:01 AM org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars
    INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
    Jun 01, 2023 9:49:01 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
    INFO: Deployment of web application directory [/abc/sw/runtime/apache-tomcat-8.5.79/webapps/host-manager] has finished in [53] ms
    Jun 01, 2023 9:49:01 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
    INFO: Deploying web application directory [/abc/sw/runtime/apache-tomcat-8.5.79/webapps/manager]
    Jun 01, 2023 9:49:01 AM org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars
    INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
    Jun 01, 2023 9:49:01 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
    INFO: Deployment of web application directory [/abc/sw/runtime/apache-tomcat-8.5.79/webapps/manager] has finished in [56] ms
    Jun 01, 2023 9:49:01 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
    INFO: Deploying web application directory [/abc/sw/runtime/apache-tomcat-8.5.79/webapps/adminui]
    Jun 01, 2023 9:49:02 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
    INFO: Deployment of web application directory [/abc/sw/runtime/apache-tomcat-8.5.79/webapps/adminui] has finished in [1,244] ms
    Jun 01, 2023 9:49:02 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
    INFO: Deploying web application directory [/abc/sw/runtime/apache-tomcat-8.5.79/webapps/alarmcfg]
    Jun 01, 2023 9:49:16 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
    INFO: Deployment of web application directory [/abc/sw/runtime/apache-tomcat-8.5.79/webapps/alarmcfg] has finished in [13,051] ms
    Jun 01, 2023 9:49:16 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
    INFO: Deploying web application directory [/abc/sw/runtime/apache-tomcat-8.5.79/webapps/universeupdateinstaller]
    Jun 01, 2023 9:49:16 AM org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars
    INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
    Jun 01, 2023 9:49:16 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
    INFO: Deployment of web application directory [/abc/sw/runtime/apache-tomcat-8.5.79/webapps/universeupdateinstaller] has finished in [274] ms
    Jun 01, 2023 9:49:16 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
    INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["https-jsse-nio-8443"]
    Jun 01, 2023 9:49:16 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
    INFO: Server startup in 15359 ms
```

**hs_err_pid54728.log**

```
    # A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
    #
    #  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=**0x00007fe638000368**, pid=54728, tid=0x00007fe625309700
    #
    # JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_333-b31) (build 1.8.0_333-b31)
    # Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.333-b31 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
    # Problematic frame:
    # C  **0x00007fe638000368**
    #
    # Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
    #
    # If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
    #   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
    # The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
    # See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
    #
    
    ---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------
    
    Current thread (0x00007fe641393800):  JavaThread "https-jsse-nio-8443-exec-15121" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=63271, stack(0x00007fe625209000,0x00007fe62530a000)]
    
    siginfo: si_signo: 11 (SIGSEGV), si_code: 2 (SEGV_ACCERR), si_addr: **0x00007fe638000368**
    
    Registers:
    RAX=0x00007fe638000318, RBX=0x00000000a010000a, RCX=0x0000000000000010, RDX=0x00007fe625307bc8
    RSP=0x00007fe625307ba8, RBP=0x00007fe625307c18, RSI=0x00007fe638f80fc0, RDI=0x00007fe638daf530
    R8 =0x0000000000000000, R9 =0x0000000004000001, R10=0x0000000000000001, R11=0x0000000000000283
    R12=0x00007fe641393a00, R13=0x00000000fc9669b0, R14=0x0000000000000000, R15=0x00007fe641393800
    RIP=**0x00007fe638000368**, EFLAGS=0x0000000000010206, CSGSFS=0x0000000000000033, ERR=0x0000000000000015
      TRAPNO=0x000000000000000e
    
    Top of Stack: (sp=0x00007fe625307ba8)
    0x00007fe625307ba8:   00007fe62bf81fec 00007fe625307c18
    0x00007fe625307bb8:   00007fe638f80fc0 00007fe638f80fc0
    0x00007fe625307bc8:   0000000000000042 0000000000000042
    0x00007fe625307bd8:   00007fe638daf530 00007fe62f31e950
    0x00007fe625307be8:   00007fe625307c50 0000000000000000
```

Comment: Please [don't upload text as image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/13447). Edit your question to contain all the information in text form - consider to use the editor's formatting options. Also see [ask].

Comment: If hs_err_pid54728.log is complete then there is no much to troubleshoot. May be a bug in the JDK. Try upgrading to the latest release.